# UICollectionView not updated in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uicollectionview

In my iPhone app I just parse the *JSON* from a *url* and save it to arrays.  After completing *JSON* parsing my `UICollectionView` should be updated with the new array values. But my `UICollectionView` isn't updating. Please look through my following coding

```
@interface SpecialPgms ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collecSpecial;
@end

@implementation SpecialPgms
NSMutableArray *arrTitle,*arrUrl,*arrImg;
UICollectionViewCell *cell ;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.9f];
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    self.collecSpecial.delegate=self;
    self.collecSpecial.dataSource=self;
    [self loadJSON];
}


-(void)loadJSON{
    arrTitle=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrUrl=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrImg=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [pro startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        JSONDecoder *decoder = [JSONDecoder decoderWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionStrict];


        NSData *immutableItemList = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=jiljilmedia&v=2&alt=jsonc"]];

        NSData *data =immutableItemList;
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData* data1 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSArray *returnedData = (NSArray *) [[[decoder objectWithData:data1] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"items"];



        for(NSDictionary * student in returnedData){

            NSString *strTitle=[student objectForKey:@"title"];

            NSDictionary *Thumbnail=[student objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
            NSString *strImg = Thumbnail[@"sqDefault"];
            NSDictionary *player = student[@"player"];
            NSString *strdefaultUrl = player[@"default"];
            NSString *strMobileUrl=player[@"mobile"];

            [arrTitle addObject:strTitle];
            //NSLog(@"%@",strImg);

            if(strMobileUrl.length==0){
                [arrUrl addObject:strdefaultUrl];
            }
            else{
                [arrUrl addObject:strMobileUrl];
            }
            [arrImg addObject:strImg];

        }
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgramTableView:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil] waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return arrTitle.count;

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UILabel *lab = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    lab.text= [arrImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];




    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
}

////// JSON Parsing for video links////////////////////
- (void)setProgramTableView: (NSArray*)array
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [  self.collecSpecial reloadData];
        [  self.collecSpecial.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    });

    [pro stopAnimating];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give me the solution for my not updating issues

Comment: Don't capitalize objects, I mistook `Thumbnail` for a class.

Comment: @CrimsonChris U think this is the problem

Comment: No, it's just confusing. Your code is hard to read. You may want to clean it up some more before trying to debug further.

Comment: What are you doing with tags?? `UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100]; UILabel *lab = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];` Did you actually make a custom cell that has views with those tags?

Comment: Yes i created my uicollectionviewcell image,label with the tags

Comment: Use you debugger and step through your code. I'm sure you can find the problem.

Comment: update your collectionView before method calling.you are passing nil value to method .

Comment: try to call your method like this         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgramTableView:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWitharray:arrImg] waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: @karthikeyan yes i tried this also.It's also not working

Comment: @karthikeyan can you provide the sample tutorial for reloading uicollectionview datas.

Comment: @karthikeyan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796891/uicollectionview-reloaddata-not-functioning-properly-in-ios-7

Comment: reload your colletionView before this line [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgramTableView:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil] waitUntilDone:YES];