# UICollectionView not refreshing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am downloading some images and inserting them into my UICollectionView

These are my class members

```
var myItems:[UIImage] = []
var myView: UICollectionView?
```

I have a timer function that receives img:UIImage object. I insert that into my UICollectionView like this

```
        self.myItems.insert(img, atIndex: self.myItems.count)
        var count:Int? = self.myView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0)
        var index:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: count!, inSection: 0)
        self.myView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([index])
```

I also have this function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.myItems.count;
}
```

and this one:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    cell.textLabel.text = "Text \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.imageView.image = myItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cellbg"))
    return cell
}
```

However my view does not show the new images immediately. I have to tap on the empty screen, then the new cell appears with its image. Also I cannot scroll the view if there are more cells that will fit in the view.

How do I refresh the view? Is there something wrong with the way I am dequeuing the cell?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to reload `UICollectionView`.

```
self.myView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2):

reloadData did not quite work

then I stumbled on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133691/1717642)

What fixed the problem was calling reloadData from the main thread.