# Xamarin iOS collectionView reloadData not working properly

Tags: ios, xamarin, cells, reloaddata, collectionview

I searched all around the web and found .. **NOTHING**

So let me tell you my problem! I have this :

- 1 collection View
- 1 datasource
- 2 layout
- 2 prototyp cells

Then I want to make 2 different styles , in grid and in list to display items.

My problem is when I use ReloadData(), the 1st time, it's OK, but the others times, cells are changing. I don't know why, I don't know how to avoid this changes..

See my code :

In Constructor

```
collectionViewTransactions.CollectionViewLayout = new CollectionViewLayoutGrid();
collectionViewTransactions.DataSource = new TransactionCollectionViewSource();
```

In 1 of method button to switch

```
private void TransactionsChangeToGrid(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        allCategoryTmplViewController.IsGrid = true;

        collectionViewTransactions.CollectionViewLayout = new CollectionViewLayoutGrid();
        collectionViewTransactions.ReloadData();
    }
```

In my GetCell method in my datasource

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Transaction transaction = Transactions[indexPath.Row];


        if(allCategoryTmplViewController.IsGrid)
        {
            var cell = (TransactionCellGrid)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("transactionGrid", indexPath);
            cell.UpdateRow(transaction);
            return cell;
        }
        else if (!allCategoryTmplViewController.IsGrid)
        {
            var cell = (TransactionCellList)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("transactionList", indexPath);
            cell.UpdateRow(transaction);
            return cell;
        }
        return new UICollectionViewCell();
    }
```

It works the 1st time, but after it doesn't !

Do I have to use invalidateLayout() method ? and if so, where ? and when ?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796891

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Yes! You have to clean the cell each time you reuse the cell.
For example here, in my "UpdateRow" the first statement is to clean my cell. Then I affect again values..